# How to get facebook user from page feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have a facebook page and users can write on the wall. Using Graph API 2.11, how can I get user who wrote the post??

I am using:

```
{app_id}?fields=feed{full_picture,message,id}
```

And the example output is:

```
"data": [
  {
    "message": "Test",
    "id": "141283311118516_642137642621111"
  }
]
```

would be nice if in the result there would be user ID.... is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to ask for the "from" field, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

for example: `/{Page-ID}?fields=feed{full_picture,message,id,from}`

Btw, you need to use a Page Token to get the user data. Which means that you can only get it if you manage the Page.

Comment: It's good, but in the result "from" section appears only where the posts were written by the page. When the post is made by any user the "from" section is empty

Comment: it´s in my answer, but i have to ask specifically because it sounds like the issue: do you manage the page and are you using a page token of that page for the api call?